# pass error message from action method to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

This is my action method containing the business logic. I want to show error message from this action method in the jsp. The control goes to the jsp but the error message does not show up.In my jsp i have this code to display error message:

```
<html:errors/>
```

I am new to struts. Also in eclipse it says that `saveErrors` method is deprecated. i know how to display errors using validate method of the bean class which extends `ActionForm`.

```
 public ActionForward upload(....)
    {
     if(noOfColumns>7)
                  {
                      errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR, new ActionMessage("error.file.maxCols")); 
                     saveErrors(request,errors);

                     return mapping.findForward("uploadVIPProcess");
                  }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found it. This was very simple:

```
public ActionForward upload(....)
    {
              errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR, new ActionMessage("error.file.maxCols")); 
              saveErrors(request,errors);
              return (new ActionForward(mapping.getInput()));
    }
```

so the only difference is instead of:

```
return mapping.findForward("uploadVIPProcess");
```

I changed it to:

```
return (new ActionForward(mapping.getInput()));
```

and it's working just fine:)

Answer (score 0):

The docs explicitly state what to do:

> **Deprecated**. Use `saveErrors(HttpServletRequest, ActionMessages)` instead.
>
> This will be removed after Struts 1.2.